# Block repeated requests in Wicket

Tags: java, request, wicket, servlet-filters

The wicket page has links that are being activated by pressing a numeric key.
`onClick()` method calls database logic to save some values. 
The problem appears when the user presses the button continuously and wicket receives one more request before it has finished the first one. The result is `StalePageException`.

```
    org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.StalePageException
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.getStoredPage(PageProvider.java:301)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:257)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:165)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.getPage(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:100)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:165)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The question is how to filter all requests until the first one is done?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `isVersioned()` and returning `true` in the target `Page` ?

Comment: Thank you for the response! 
Yes, I have tried this but still unsuccessful. The target page is the same.
Moreover it would be great to filter such request somewhere on upper level. May be in `RequestCycleListener`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked before in the wicket-user lists, and the answer was to disable your components/prevent further interaction until the request ends.

In your case, just removing/blocking `onClick()`'s behavior would be enough.

- [Double click on submit button](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/double-click-on-submit-button-td1922241.html)
- [Preventing double-click of AjaxButtons in ModalWindow](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Preventing-double-click-of-AjaxButtons-in-ModalWindow-td2289480.html)
- [How to prevent user from double-clicking a non-Ajax component](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/How-to-prevent-user-from-double-clicking-a-non-Ajax-component-td3328308.html)

Also worth mentioning that if the requests are Ajax, you can specify a *drop behavior* so that in a scenario where multiple requests are sent, only the last one is processed. You can achieve that by overriding `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.getChannelName()` and returning anything ending with `|d`.

Comment: Yes, this helps to prevent StalePageException but causes to grow amount of server threads on each hit:
`Daemon Thread ["http-bio-81"-exec-320] (Running) 
Daemon Thread ["http-bio-81"-exec-322] (Running) 
Daemon Thread ["http-bio-81"-exec-323] (Running) 
Daemon Thread ["http-bio-81"-exec-324] (Running) 
Daemon Thread ["http-bio-81"-exec-325] (Running)`

and sooner or later (if the key still pressed) leads to `org.apache.wicket.page.CouldNotLockPageException: Could not lock page 1523. Attempt lasted 1 minute
 at ...`

Comment: P.S. in this particular case the requests are not Ajax

Comment: Without knowing much about how the page is built, couldn't `onClick()` set a flag that would prevent itself from executing again, and when the first request ends, at page reload, reset that flag? I know this doesn't address the _filtering requests_ issue, which btw I'm not aware of how to resolve :)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help! 
But nevertheless will be glad to get any idea from anyone how to _filter_ requests.

Comment: I will also keep an eye on this question in case there's an answer that addresses the issue directly. I've retagged the question in case there's a non-wicket specific answer to it.

Comment: Having the same problem here. Some navigation buttons between forms - if the user clicks next quickly in consession it fails on IE with StalePageException but works fine on Firefox. It looks like Firefox has a different way of handling multiple submit than IE.